# wordpress login page not getting load-styles.php?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, authentication, stylesheet

I have just completed a clone of an instance of wordpress to a sub directory on the same server.

The admin panel is looking fine, the pages are loading however, navigating to '..../wp-login.php', the login page isn't loading the stylesheet, but loads everywhere else.

I have checked the network tab and found the attached:

in the sub directory:

[isn't loading stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZszT7.png)

at root level:

[is loading stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WgWq.png)

I can't seem to find any documentation on this online, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

as an additional point, on line 22 of the rendered login page, this is missing:

https://www.example.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,buttons,forms,l10n,login&ver=4.9.3' type='text/css' media='all' />

so its not loading at all. :/

Comment: Have you use any plugin to design the login page? if not then clear the browser cache or open the same page in another browser. if yes then reactivate the respective plugin after login.

Comment: Hi, I will check and see, but as far as I'm aware, there doesn't seem to be one. But I will check now and get back to you.

Comment: _“isn't loading stylesheet”_ - is that listing _all_ requests, or do you maybe have that filtered in some way, so that for example a request that just 404s would not show up in that list? What does the browser console say?

Comment: so no errors in the console, and there are no filters have been placed in. I've checked the plugins and there are none for login pages and also, the same issue is showing in firefox, opera and safari. Really strange as the dashboard is styling fine.

Comment: just as a follow up, on line 22 of the response, this is missing: 

just a follow up on line 22 of the response: 

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.example.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load%5B%5D=dashicons,buttons,forms,l10n,login&amp;ver=4.9.3' type='text/css' media='all' />

Answer (score 11):

Try to add in **wp-config.php** this code for a quick fix:

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

After that, you have time for debugging.